# How do I configure an Amazon AWS Lambda function to prevent tailing the log in the response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

Please see this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html

> **LogType**
>
> You can set this optional parameter to Tail in the request
>   only if you specify the InvocationType parameter with value
>   RequestResponse. In this case, AWS Lambda returns the base64-encoded
>   last 4 KB of log data produced by your Lambda function in the
>   x-amz-log-result header.
>
> Valid Values: None | Tail

So this means any user with valid credentials for invoking a function can also read the logs this function emits?

If so, this is an obvious vulnerability that can give some attacker useful information regarding processing of invalid input.

How do I configure an Amazon AWS Lambda function to prevent tailing the log in the response?

**Update 1**

1) Regarding the comment: "*If a hacker can call your Lambda function, you have 
more problems than seeing log files.*"

Not true: Lambda functions are also meant to be called directly form client code, using the SDK.

As an example, see the picture below from the book "AWS Lambda in Action":

[image]

2) Regarding the comment: "*How is this a vulnerability exactly? Only someone you have provided AWS IAM credentials would be able to invoke the Lambda function.*"

Of course, clients do have some credentials, most of the time (for example, 
from having signed in to your mobile app with their Facebook account, through Amazon Cognito). Am I supposed to trust all my users?

3) Regarding the comment: "*Only if you have put some secure information to be logged.*"

Logs may contain sensible information. I'm not talking about secure information like passwords, but simply information to help the development team debugging, or the security team finding out about attacks. Applications may log all kinds of information, including why some invalid input failed, which can help an attacker learn what is the valid input. Also, attackers can see all the information the security team is logging about their attacks. Not good. Even privacy may be at risk depending on what you log.

**Update 2**

It would also solve my problem if I could somehow detect the `Tail` parameter in the Lambda code. Then I would just fail with a "Tail now allowed" message. Unfortunately the `Context` object doesn't seem to contain this information.

Comment: How is this a vulnerability exactly? Only someone you have provided AWS IAM credentials would be able to invoke the Lambda function directly via the AWS API.

Comment: (in addition to comment above) and only if you have put some secure information to be logged as output of the lambda function

Comment: This parameter is only used during an Invoke API call. If a hacker can call your Lambda function, you have more problems than seeing log files.

Comment: Please see the update above (the answer to your comments improved the clarity of the question).

Comment: "clients do have some credentials" -- but the policies/role for that credentials should not normally include "allow" for "lambda:Invoke".

Comment: I've looked at the diagramm from the book. Yes, in the suggested workflow you do have the problem. The correct approach is that client doesn't access lambda functions directly, but through API Gateways.

Comment: @olpa Gateway API is not free, demands development, complicates management, and thus should not be used just to hide information Lambda should not be sending in the first place.

Comment: ```Valid Values: None | Tail``` why setting this option to None isn't solving your problem?

Comment: @ÇağatayGürtürk This option is a parameter of the request. An attacker will make its own request, and he may use the Tail option.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't configure AWS Lambda to prevent tailing the log in the response. However, you could use your own logging component instead of using the one provided by Amazon Lambda to avoid the possibility to expose them via the `LogType` parameter.

Otherwise, I see your point about adding complexity, but using API Gateway is the most common solution to provide the possibility to invoke Lambdas for clients applications that you do not trust.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, not only it's a bad practice, it's obviously (as you already understood) introducing security vulnerabilities.

If you look carefully in the book you will also find this part:

[image]

which explains that in order to be more secure, the client requests should hit Amazon API gateway which will expose a clean API interface and which will call the relevant lambda-function without exposing it to the outer-world.

An example of such API is demo'ed in a previous page:

[image]

By introducing a middle-layer between the client and AWS-lambda, we take care of authentication, authorization, access and all other points of potential vulnerability.

Comment: The API Gateway is not free and introduces extra latency. It's basically introducing an extra unnecessary step, and complicates management (easy management should be an AWS-Lambda advantage to start with). 
If my service is not meant to "expose a clean web API that can be consumed by external services", I don't see why I should be forced to do so only for the sake of fixing this Tail problem.

Comment: So far I don't see other advantages of using the API Gateway. You can also have authentication and authorization by directly accessing AWS-Lambdas. Caching I don't need. Throttling is also done by AWS-Lambdas, and the Amazon SDK even retries automatically.

Comment: "authentication and authorization by directly accessing AWS-Lambdas" - that means that you'll need to create IAM user for each one of your users and manage it... (which costs money as well btw).

Comment: As for "It's basically introducing an extra unnecessary step" - well, in the case that you showed us it's obviously not unnecessary. If your use-case was that you have only a small number of users, each of which is trustable, you could use the approach of "not introducing another layer" but since this is not the scenario you're describing...

Comment: Allowing direct access to the backend can introduce other vulnerabilities: a malicious user can do more than accessing the logs: a malicious user can mess with the parameters that are sent in the request and expose weaknesses in your code.

Comment: A malicious user can mess with the REST parameters of the API Gateway that are sent in the request and expose weaknesses in the code. Input parameters should be validated in both cases. I don't see a difference. In my use case I believe the API Gateway is a necessary step, yes, but only because of the Trail option, hence this question. The book you and I cited talks about the API Gateway as something good but optional. By the way, I believe the Trail option exists because Amazon wants to be able to show the log in the console, when you test Lambdas through the console.

Comment: What I meant by "clean" is that your code might return 500 with a stacktrace for invalid output, and this stacktrace can expose details about your service, fronting it with API gateway - the end user will get only the 500 error without additional information. That said, I totally agree that ideally a good validation should take place. As for the Trail, I see your point and it would make sense to open a ticket with AWS raising this issue, adding a relevant role to IAM, something like: ViewTrailEnabled can solve this issue - maybe they'll consider it.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Also another solution is to let the Lambda call some method in the Context object to check the Trail option, and another to disable trailing.

Comment: True, as along as the malicious user cannot modify this Context object

Answer (score 1):

**This is a comment.**
While this should be a comment, I am sorry that I do not have yet enough stackoverflow reputation to do so.

Before commenting on this, please note that lambda Invoke may result in more than one execution of your lambda (per AWS documentation)

> Invocations occur at least once in response to an event and functions must be idempotent to handle this.

As the LogType is documented as a valid option, I don't think you can prevent it in your backend. However, you need to have a workaround to handle it. I can think of

1- Generate a junk 4KB tail log (by console.log() for example). Then, the attacker will get a junk info. (incur cost only in case of attacker)

2- Use step functions. This is not only to hide the log but to overcome the problem of 'Invocations occur at least once' and have a predictable execution of your backend. It incurs cost though.

Comment: Wow, invocations may run more than once per request? That sucks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFtUUx4Zybw&feature=youtu.be&t=15m6s

Comment: Junk log? But I want to log my real information (for my own access).

Comment: Of course, you can log your information. So, after logging your real information and just before calling context.succeed() or callback() you add a log of 4KB size. However, that will not hide "Duration: xxx ms Billed Duration: xxx ms Memory Size: xxx MB Max Memory Used: xx MB". For example, if you log a text of  many "A" console.log("A.........") the logResult will include "BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQQ......." instead of your informative log.

Comment: But then all my logs will contain 4KB of garbage. And I will not incur cost only in case of attack.